# Machine epsilon subtraction in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical, epsilon

Using MATLAB: Why does `1-eps == 1-eps*4/3` return `FALSE`. With M mantissa bits, shouldn't `eps*4/3` be 1.0101...*2^-M which will be rounded to `eps` when subtracted from 1?

Comment: No.  Try examining `eps` and `eps*4/3`.  You'll see that they're unequal.  Besides which `eps` gives you the maximum floating point error expected between a real number (i.e. with as many bits of precision as possible) and one stored on a computer.  Also, in MATLAB, `eps = 2^-52`, so doing `eps*4/3 = (4/3)*2^-52` and that's also why the equality doesn't hold.

Comment: @rayryeng I get that `eps` and `eps*4/3` aren't equal by themselves, but I though when they were both subtracted from 1 the `eps*4/3` wouldn't be able to maintain accuracy. Also then, why does `1-eps/2 == 1-eps*4/3` hold? I though with M bits `eps` could not be rounded to fractions?

Comment: I think rounding point is not first bit. After typing 'format hex' on matlab window, I check 'eps*(4/3)', Answer was '3cb5555555555555', but when I tried 'eps*(5/4)', the answer was '3cb4000000000000'. and '1-eps*(5/4)==1-eps' is true.

Comment: You aren't going small enough. This works: `1e-323 == 9.8813e-324`.

Comment: But `1+eps == 1+ 4/3*(eps)` returns true..